# Excel data in rows and columns to be reformatted

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have data in Excel in a staggered format.  There is a customer ID in the left-most column and the details of that customer are in different rows within different columns.  I need to rearrange the data into one single row for each customer. It is in the same format for all other customers.

```
CustomerID FirstName LastName Education Training TrainingYear City State Zip
1          John       C       Masters
1                                      SAP
1                                                2017
1                                                             LA
1                                                                   CA
1                                                                        91433
2          Max        G       Bachelors
2                                       Oracle
2                                               2015
2                                                             NR
2                                                                  CA
2                                                                        91234
```

Comment: @fixer1234 You should really post that as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A", ROW()*6-10))`

Changing "A" to the corresponding column (B for Firstname, C for Lastname, D for Education, and so on) and changing "-10" to the corresponding column (-10 for Education, -9 for Training, -8 for TrainingYear, ... , -5 for Zip)

---

For Training column

`=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("E", ROW()*6-9))`

For Zip Column

`=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("H", ROW()*6-6))`

---

Credits to **fixer1234** comment.

---

This intuitive method does NOT work (or at least not as convenient, because AutoFill does not recognize the simple 6 step pattern):

```
CustomerID | Firstname | Lastname | Education | Training | TrainingYear | City | State | Zip
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=A2        | =B2       | =C2      | =D2       | =E3      | =F4          | =G5  | =H6   | =I7
=A8        | =B8       | =C8      | =D8       | =E9      | =F10         | =G11 | =H12  | =I13
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using some formulas that calculate what cells to use based on the row, as Adi Nugroho's answer does.  In fact you could take it a step farther and use a single formula for all the cells.

### 1: Single Formula Solution

Here's one example (there are multiple approaches that could be used).  Copy the column headings to another sheet.  Then put this formula in A2:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,ROW()*6-12+(COLUMN()>4)*(COLUMN()-4),COLUMN()-1)
```

Copy it across the columns, then replicate the row as needed.  It gives you:

[image: single formula]

**Explanation:**

The OFFSET function anchors your new table to the first cell of the original data, then defines each cell as an offset from there.

`ROW()*6-12` converts the original six row pattern to a single row interval.

`(COLUMN()>4)*(COLUMN()-4)` bumps the row reference for columns E and beyond.  The first parentheses contain a logical test for whether you are beyond the 4th column, returning `1` if true and `0` if false.  That is multiplied by the column number in excess to 4 to reflect the data pattern (column 5 drops one row).

`COLUMN()-1` adjusts the actual column to an offset (column 1 of your result is `0` offset from column 1 of the data).

So that single formula finds the right source cell for every cell in your result.

---

### 2: No Brain Cells Required Solution

As an alternative, there is a really simple solution that doesn't require any fancy functions.

Start with your data in Sheet1:

[image: data]

- Copy the column headings to a new sheet.
- For the first row, enter the first cell reference (in A2) to the data in Sheet 1:

  =sheet1!A2

Copy it to B2, C2, and D2.  Then copy it to E3, F4, G5, H6, and I7.  That will automatically point the cells to the right place.  Then drag (move) the cells in columns E through I up to row 2 and the formulas will be retained.  So Row 2 will contain:

```
A2: =sheet1!A2
B2: =sheet1!B2
C2: =sheet1!C2
D2: =sheet1!D2
E2: =sheet1!E3
F2: =sheet1!F4
G2: =sheet1!G5
H2: =sheet1!H6
I2: =sheet1!I7
```

- Select the Row 2 values and replicate them down the page for as many rows as you have data on Sheet 1.  It will look like this:

[image: Step 1]

It has your single-row data, but it is in the first rows of each six-row group.  Note that instead of rows that are blank in columns B through I, you may have rows with zeros in those columns if column A was formatted as a number (that's not a problem).

We eliminate the extra rows with another step.

- Select the whole table and turn on filtering.
- Filter on Column B and select to show only empty cells (or zero if that's what you got).  The filter will hide the rows with your values and look like this (or like rows of zeros except for column A); i.e., just the extra rows:

[image: Filter]

- Select all of the visible data rows and delete rows via the right-click menu:

[image: delete rows]

- Now turn filtering off and you have your result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I need to rearrange the data into one single row for each customer.
>   It is in the same format for all other customers.

If you are comfortable with running Macros. Here is a simple nested loop:

```
Sub moveAndCleanup()
    Call move
    Call cleanup
End Sub

Sub move()
    Dim row, col, i, j As Integer
    row = 2
    col = 4
    j = 6
        Do While Cells(row, 1).Value <> ""
            For i = 1 To 5
                Cells(row, col + i).Value = Cells(row + i, col + i).Value
            Next i
            row = row + j
        Loop
End Sub

Sub cleanup()
    Dim row, col, i, j As Integer
    row = 2
    col = 4
    j = 6
        Do While Cells(row, 1).Value <> ""
            For i = 1 To 5
                Cells(row + i, col + i).Value = ""
                Cells(row + i, 1).Value = ""
            Next i
            row = row + j
        Loop
End Sub
```

**But remember to copy your data, or copy your workbook first, because you CANNOT UNDO a Macro.**